# What's going on in this sum?

Tags: neural-networks, artificial-intelligence

This is part of a slope calculation example to update the new weight of a neural network from the slope. From a [Deep Learning course on DataCamp](https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/deep-learning-in-python/optimizing-a-neural-network-with-backward-propagation?ex=6)

My math is a bit dodgy and what I don't understand is how this sum equals 2.24? What's the order of operations here that gives this number? What am I missing here?  2 is the original weight, -24 is the slope, 0.01 is the learning rate.

2 - 0.01 (-24) = 2.24

Comment: (-24) here is a value, negative 24; -.01 times -24 is (positive) .24, and then that plus 2 is 2.24 - because 2 - .01*(-24) = 2+(-.01)*(-24). (Note that canonically multiplication and division are generally taken before addition and subtraction, especially in algorithmics work, since that's the precedence for virtually any computer language)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Ah got it. My calculator was not turning that first sum `.01 * -24` into a positive number. Thank you!